# Key, Value Count in BigQuery

Tags: dictionary, count, key, google-bigquery

Implementation of the following problems in BigQuery:

1. I have this following dictionary in JSON format. How can I count total number of key, value inside `id` dictionary?

```
{"fil":{"property":{"id":{id_1:"a",id_2:"b",id_3:"c",id_4:"d"}}}}
```

2. The value `"a"` can appear in any of the ids (`id_1`,...,`id_5`) in multiple such dictionaries. Need to calculate number of times `"a"` has appeared in any of the ids in any of the dictionaries.

Comment: how you store your dictionaries in GBQ table. provide schema and example

Answer (score 0):

For 1., using [standard SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/sql-reference/) (uncheck the "Use Legacy SQL" box under "Show Options") you can use the comma operator to take the cross product of the table and the repeated field:

```
WITH MyTable AS (
  SELECT STRUCT(STRUCT(ARRAY<STRUCT<key STRING, value STRING>>[('id_1', 'a'), ('id_2', 'b'), ('id_3', 'c'), ('id_4', 'd')] AS id) AS property) AS fil
  UNION ALL SELECT STRUCT(STRUCT(ARRAY<STRUCT<key STRING, value STRING>>[('id_1', 'b'), ('id_3', 'e')] AS id) AS property) AS fil
  UNION ALL SELECT STRUCT(STRUCT(ARRAY<STRUCT<key STRING, value STRING>>[] AS id) AS property) AS fil
  UNION ALL SELECT STRUCT(STRUCT(ARRAY<STRUCT<key STRING, value STRING>>[('id_4', 'a'), ('id_2', 'c')] AS id) AS property) AS fil)
SELECT
  COUNT(DISTINCT id.key) AS num_keys,
  COUNT(DISTINCT id.value) AS num_values
FROM MyTable t, t.fil.property.id AS id;
+----------+------------+
| num_keys | num_values |
+----------+------------+
|        4 |          5 |
+----------+------------+
```

Using legacy SQL, you can accomplish something similar using `EXACT_COUNT_DISTINCT` (you probably won't need to flatten), although it's harder to set up an inline example.

For 2., you can apply a similar approach using standard SQL of flattening and then counting the number of occurrences of `"a"` with `COUNTIF(id.value = "a")`. In legacy SQL, alternatively, you can use `COUNT(t.fil.property.id.value = "a")`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have your dictionaries stored in Your Table as string in field named json

> The key for answer is below query.

It parses json field and extract all the key/value pair along with their parent (dictionary name)

```
SELECT parent, key, value 
FROM JS((
  SELECT json FROM  
    (SELECT '{"fil":{"property":{"id":{"id_1":"a","id_2":"b","id_3":"c","id_4":"d"}}}}' AS json),
    (SELECT '{"fil":{"property":{"type":{"id_1":"x","id_2":"a","id_3":"y","id_4":"z"}, "category":{"id_1":"v","id_2":"w","id_3":"a","id_4":"b"}}}}' AS json)
  ),
  json,                                    // Input columns
  "[{name: 'parent', type:'string'},       // Output schema
   {name: 'key', type:'string'},
   {name: 'value', type:'string'}]",
   "function(r, emit) {                    // The function
      x = JSON.parse(r.json);
      processKey(x, '');
      function processKey(node, parent) {
        Object.keys(node).map(function(key) {
          value = node[key].toString();
          if (value !== '[object Object]') {
            emit({parent:parent, key:key, value:value});
          } else {
            if (parent !== '' && parent.substr(parent.length-1) !== '.') {parent += '.'};
            processKey(node[key], parent + key);
          };
        });         
      };
    }"
  )
```

Result of above query is as below

```
parent                  key     value    
fil.property.id         id_1    a    
fil.property.id         id_2    b    
fil.property.id         id_3    c    
fil.property.id         id_4    d    
fil.property.type       id_1    x    
fil.property.type       id_2    a    
fil.property.type       id_3    y    
fil.property.type       id_4    z    
fil.property.category   id_1    v    
fil.property.category   id_2    w    
fil.property.category   id_3    a    
fil.property.category   id_4    b
```

From there, you can easily get both answers:

> Q1: How can I count total number of key, value inside "id" (**each**) dictionary

```
SELECT parent, COUNT(1) AS key_value_pairs  
FROM JS((
  SELECT json FROM  
    (SELECT '{"fil":{"property":{"id":{"id_1":"a","id_2":"b","id_3":"c","id_4":"d"}}}}' AS json),
    (SELECT '{"fil":{"property":{"type":{"id_1":"x","id_2":"a","id_3":"y","id_4":"z"}, "category":{"id_1":"v","id_2":"w","id_3":"a","id_4":"b"}}}}' AS json)
  ),
  json,                                    // Input columns
  "[{name: 'parent', type:'string'},       // Output schema
   {name: 'key', type:'string'},
   {name: 'value', type:'string'}]",
   "function(r, emit) {                    // The function
      x = JSON.parse(r.json);
      processKey(x, '');
      function processKey(node, parent) {
        Object.keys(node).map(function(key) {
          value = node[key].toString();
          if (value !== '[object Object]') {
            emit({parent:parent, key:key, value:value});
          } else {
            if (parent !== '' && parent.substr(parent.length-1) !== '.') {parent += '.'};
            processKey(node[key], parent + key);
          };
        });         
      };
    }"
  )
GROUP BY parent
```

result is

```
parent                  key_value_pairs  
fil.property.id         4    
fil.property.type       4    
fil.property.category   4
```

> Q2: Need to calculate number of times "a" (**any value**) has appeared in any of the ids in any of the dictionaries.

```
SELECT value, COUNT(1) AS value_appearances
FROM JS((
  SELECT json FROM  
    (SELECT '{"fil":{"property":{"id":{"id_1":"a","id_2":"b","id_3":"c","id_4":"d"}}}}' AS json),
    (SELECT '{"fil":{"property":{"type":{"id_1":"x","id_2":"a","id_3":"y","id_4":"z"}, "category":{"id_1":"v","id_2":"w","id_3":"a","id_4":"b"}}}}' AS json)
  ),
  json,                                    // Input columns
  "[{name: 'parent', type:'string'},       // Output schema
   {name: 'key', type:'string'},
   {name: 'value', type:'string'}]",
   "function(r, emit) {                    // The function
      x = JSON.parse(r.json);
      processKey(x, '');
      function processKey(node, parent) {
        Object.keys(node).map(function(key) {
          value = node[key].toString();
          if (value !== '[object Object]') {
            emit({parent:parent, key:key, value:value});
          } else {
            if (parent !== '' && parent.substr(parent.length-1) !== '.') {parent += '.'};
            processKey(node[key], parent + key);
          };
        });         
      };
    }"
  )
GROUP BY value  

value   value_appearances    
a       3    
b       2    
c       1    
d       1    
x       1    
y       1    
z       1    
v       1    
w       1
```

Answer (score 0):

As other answers were to hard for me I made regular expression that works for string:int dict

```
SELECT 
        *, REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(my_dict_column, r'"(\w+": \d+)') as keys
FROM test.test_table
```

From that you can do keys, values and etc