# Transformation of multiple values in complex string field to a countable structure

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, bigdata, re2

e.g. for the data in one field:

```
"{""noAbsolutValues"":{""HIGHLIGHTS"":[""engineData_startStopSystem"",""search_parkingAssistants"",""heatingCooling_climatisation"",""multimedia_navigationSystem"",""search_seatHeating"",""wheel_multifunctionalWheel""],""CLIMATISATION"":[""selector_climatisation_airCondition""],""MULTIMEDIA"":[""multimedia_navigationSystem"",""multimedia_usbInterface"",""multimedia_radioTuner""],""HEATER"":[""selector_coDriverSeats_electricHeated"",""selector_driverSeats_electricHeated""],""ASSISTANTS"":[""assistants_parkingSensors"",""assistants_cruiseControl""]},""dateValues"":{}}"
```

At first i separated my needed values with the following query:

```
SELECT
ARRAY_TO_STRING(REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(filter_query,r'"[[:alpha:]]+_[[:alpha:]]+_[[:alpha:]]+"|"[[:alpha:]]+_[[:alpha:]]+"'),";") as fq
FROM `table`
```

My result are different kind of rows with values separated by semicolon.

e.g. for one row:

```
"engineData_startStopSystem";"search_parkingAssistants";"heatingCooling_climatisation";"multimedia_navigationSystem";"search_seatHeating";"wheel_multifunctionalWheel";"selector_climatisation_airCondition";"multimedia_navigationSystem";"multimedia_usbInterface";"multimedia_radioTuner";"selector_coDriverSeats_electricHeated";"selector_driverSeats_electricHeated";"assistants_parkingSensors";"assistants_cruiseControl"
```

Now I have to count all variants, perfect would be that i would have one row for the value and one for the count result.

Big thanks for all help

Comment: Will your `HIGHLIGHTS`, `CLIMATISATION`, `MULTIMEDIA`, `HEATER`, `ASSISTANTS` groupings always be present?  Will there ever be unexpected/new groupings?  A fixed set will make this query easier.

Comment: no, this groupings are not needed for this query. I guess that this structure depends on the filter navigation which it belongs to.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the example provided in this thread will help you out.
[Key, Value Count in BigQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37946049/key-value-count-in-bigquery)

Test data:

> {"fil":{"property":{"id":{id_1:"a",id_2:"b",id_3:"c",id_4:"d"}}}}

Query:

```
WITH MyTable AS (
  SELECT STRUCT(STRUCT(ARRAY<STRUCT<key STRING, value STRING>>[('id_1', 'a'), ('id_2', 'b'), ('id_3', 'c'), ('id_4', 'd')] AS id) AS property) AS fil
  UNION ALL SELECT STRUCT(STRUCT(ARRAY<STRUCT<key STRING, value STRING>>[('id_1', 'b'), ('id_3', 'e')] AS id) AS property) AS fil
  UNION ALL SELECT STRUCT(STRUCT(ARRAY<STRUCT<key STRING, value STRING>>[] AS id) AS property) AS fil
  UNION ALL SELECT STRUCT(STRUCT(ARRAY<STRUCT<key STRING, value STRING>>[('id_4', 'a'), ('id_2', 'c')] AS id) AS property) AS fil)
SELECT
  COUNT(DISTINCT id.key) AS num_keys,
  COUNT(DISTINCT id.value) AS num_values
FROM MyTable t, t.fil.property.id AS id;
```

Output:

```
+----------+------------+
| num_keys | num_values |
+----------+------------+
|        4 |          5 |
+----------+------------+
```

Comment: Looks like it may fit but I don´t understand the logic behind. Seems like my skill level is to low. I don´t understand how to embed the array structure from my data in this `SELECT` `STRUCT` construction.

Comment: As you can see in our [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#with-clause), the WITH clause contains one or more named subqueries which execute every time a subsequent SELECT statement references them. Any clause or subquery can reference subqueries you define in the WITH clause. This includes any SELECT statements on either side of a set operator, such as UNION.
More info on [arrays](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/arrays) and [struct](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-types)

Comment: If it did fit your need and you understand now the logic behind it, please accept the answer so it can help the community.